# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle, python-unicode

I know, it has been asked several times, but none of the answer gave me a solution

Here is the code (Python 2.7):

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

connstr = 'MyConstr'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
cur = conn.cursor()

xl = pd.ExcelFile("C:\\TEMP\\for_kkod.xlsx")
df = xl.parse(0)

for i in df.index:
    s = u"insert into MY_TABLE values({0}, '{1}')".format(int(df.iloc[i]['kkod']), df.iloc[i]['kkodnev'])
    print s
    print type(s)
    cur.execute(s)
```

The result of the 2 prints are this:

```
insert into MY_TABLE values(10, 'Készítés')
<type 'unicode'>
```

As you can see the type of s is unicode but nevertheless I have this error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried with and without u"", with and without encode and decode in all possible ways but still the same error message

Any idea?

Comment: You get an *encode* error, because `cur.execute()` expects a bytestring.

Comment: Yes, but my first attempt was this: cur.execute("insert into MYTABLE values(%s, %s)", (int(df.iloc[i]['kkod']), df.iloc[i]['kkodnev']))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are feeding a Unicode SQL statement to `cursor.execute()`. That method can only take a *bytestring SQL statement*.

You should not be using string interpolation to insert your Unicode values into the SQL query (which itself is just ASCII). Use query parameters, always!

```
 s = "insert into MY_TABLE values(:0, :1)"
 cur.execute(s, (int(df.iloc[i]['kkod']), df.iloc[i]['kkodnev']))
```

Now the values to be inserted are passed in as parameters and it is up to the database adapter to worry about encoding these correcty (as well as properly escaping the values to evade SQL injection issues).

The above uses numbered (positional) arguments, you can also use named parameters, pass in the values in a dictionary with matching keys:

```
 s = "insert into MY_TABLE values(:kkod, :kkodnev)"
 cur.execute(s, {'kkod': int(df.iloc[i]['kkod']), 'kkodnev': df.iloc[i]['kkodnev']})
```

You do have to make sure both your connection and your table column is correctly configured to handle Unicode. For example, you'll have to set the `NLS_LANG` option:

```
import os
os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = '.AL32UTF8'
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have this: s = "insert into MYTABLE values(:kkod, :kkodnev)" print type(s) is: <type 'str'> and the exec:  cur.execute(s, {'kkod': int(df.iloc[i]['kkod']), 'kkodnev': df.iloc[i]['kkodnev']}), but the same error message: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Gabor: first of all, make 100% certain that the traceback includes the `cursor.execute()` line. Perhaps move the parameter dictionary definition to a separate line (`params = {'kkod': int(df.iloc[i]['kkod']), 'kkodnev': df.iloc[i]['kkodnev']}`, `cur.execute(s, params)`), and verify that the traceback still blames the `cur.execute()` call. Then verify that your database column is of the correct type to store Unicode, e.g. `NVARCHAR2`. What is `NLS_LANG` set to for you?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oracle_insert.py", line 15, in <module>
    cur.execute(s, {'kkod': int(df.iloc[i]['kkod']), 'kkodnev': df.iloc[i]['kkodnev']})
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: and same here: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oracle_insert.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.execute(s, params)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Gabor: right, that is cx_Oracle encoding your Unicode data, most likely because it either thinks Oracle wants to communicate in ASCII (the NLS_LANG setting) or because the column is not Unicode ready.

Comment: Well the column is nvarchar2(255), the database level NLS_LANGUAGE = HUNGARIAN and NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8

Comment: But is that set *when connecting*?

Comment: I'v got it! I'v forgotten to put in my code the following line (as you've suggested) os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = '.AL32UTF8'. Now it's there and it is working! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the following parameters for connection:

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(connectString, encoding="UTF-8",nencoding="UTF-8")